# What is the nuance of 解{げ}す？

Tags: word-choice, kanji, readings, definitions

Today in my JLPT text book, I came across the word `解{げ}す`.

I know that the kanji `解` means "unravel", and it can be read `解{わか}る`, and with that reading it's synonymous with `分{わ}かる`, "to understand".

When I looked up `解{げ}す` in the dictionary, it also seems to just mean "to understand" when read this way.

Which made me wonder - why use this reading instead of the usual `解{わか}る` reading? Does it carry any extra or different nuance?

Is this reading as rare as I think it is, or is it just me that hasn't come across it very often?

Comment: I mainly encounter this in the potential-negative, I think, as 解{げ}せない. It feels to me like "incomprehensible", "cannot fathom" etc., as opposed to "can't understand" -- like you can't even begin to unravel an explanation for it. It's mainly used when talking about failure to understand people's motivations, I think?

Comment: @hyperworm, answers are for answers :)

Comment: @silvermaple I felt that I had too many "I think"s to put it as an answer, and it's not exactly fleshed out ;) Well, I'll post it.

Comment: @hyperworm, have confidence in yourself (^.^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moved to answer from comments.

I mainly encounter this in the potential-negative as 解{げ}せない. As opposed to 解{わか}らない ("don't understand"), 解{げ}せない feels more like the speaker has tried and failed to unravel any kind of explanation, as if the situation seems to defy all logic - "can't fathom/comprehend" feels like a close English equivalent.

It seems to come up a lot in the context of failure to understand people's motivations.

[研究社 新和英中辞典 @ Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%9B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84):

> 彼女がなぜあんなことを言ったのか解せないよ.
>   We can't understand why she said such a thing.

[英辞郎 @ Space Alc](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%9B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/UTF-8/):

> What is beyond our comprehension is that
>   解せないのは＜that以下＞です。

Answer (score 2):

The only common usages I can think of are 解{げ}せない and 解熱{げねつ}.